# What's the maximum memory size of the redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

I am writing an App in React. I am using Redux to store my data on page.
This Data contains a huge user object ( nested max. 3 levels ) which contains all user data. I am using it almast anywhere so I think that it is good to store it in redux and not to request it from server everytime when I need it.
This Data can be about 70-80 KB but I think average size of each user will be 30-40 kb.

This data is modified with combined of 5-6 reducers and 30-50 actions.
I have one component which uses all of this data and 10-15 components which uses some part of it.

can redux store be almost 100 kb in size?

does it affect the App performance?

can any browser handle my app without any performance issues?

Can you provide your average redux store size?

What is the average number of actions and reducers one can have?

Comment: For the most part, using redux or not using it would not affect *how much* data you can store ( in the redux store or anywhere whatsoever ). Ultimately, it will be in the browser memory.

Comment: I got it. But main question how much can store be? only 5 kb? max 100kb? or even 10 mb?

Comment: can paste your data example @malkhazi

Comment: This is about average size 50kb data: https://pastebin.com/7CgXVXap
some data can be more and some can be less (  about 10 kb or 5kb )

Answer (score 19):

Open "More Tools" -> "Task Manager" in Chrome.

Open the twitter web app and find the tab in Task Manager. Mine started at 120MB.

Start scrolling and see how long it takes to crack 500MB.

I know it's not directly related to data stored in Redux considering most of it is gifs, etc, but it is related I think it demonstrates that talking about limits of 100KB is not worth the thought involved. I'd be very surprised if you could find a device with a browser that had any issues with even 10MB.

Comment: I seem to be having performance issues with a react/redux/formik application that has ~40MB in redux. But Formik might be the one to blame?

Comment: That would really all come down to how the data is structured and what operations are being run on it I would say.