# What's the limit on storage for Redux in the browser?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there a limit on how much data we can persist in Redux store? Also, at any given time when a React application is running, can we check how much data is being saved in the Redux store in real time?

Comment: See [What's the maximum memory size of the redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53719688/2873538)